# Grails resource warning log entry when using images with absolute:true

Tags: grails, resources, absolute-path

Using Grails 2.0.4.  In building emails, I use a lot of images with absolute paths.  Each one results in an annoying log entry.  Is there an easy fix?  They DO exist, it just seems the resource plugin doesn't like absolute paths.  This happens outside of localhost / dev environment too.

```
<img src="${resource(dir: 'images/brochure', file: 'arrow_up.png', absolute: 'true')}" alt="Up" />
```

results in

```
WARN  resource.ResourceTagLib  - Invocation of <r:resource> for a resource that apparently doesn't exist: http://localhost:8080/images/brochure/arrow_up.png
```

Comment: I'm also experiencing this with Grails 2.3.4. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I submitted an issue to the Grails JIRA: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPRESOURCES-256

Comment: I found a solution, see my own answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution that has been working with me for Grails 2.1.x and above (including the newest 2.3.x) is  adding these entries to your log4j config block in Config.groovy - no other code changes needed.

```
 log4j = {
           //your other stuff ...
            error 'grails.app.services.org.grails.plugin.resource'
            error 'grails.app.taglib.org.grails.plugin.resource'
            error 'grails.app.resourceMappers.org.grails.plugin.resource'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it still seems to be an issue with Grails 2.3.x. There is comment above the `resource` closure in `ResourceTagLib` that says:

> @todo this currently won't work for absolute="true" invocations, it should just passthrough these

In order to remove the warnings in the log, I overrode the `resource` closure, changing this bit:

```
...
if (!info.debug && log.warnEnabled) {
    log.warn "Invocation of <r:resource> for a resource that apparently doesn't exist: ${info.uri}"
}
...
```

to this:

```
...
if (attrs.absolute != true && !info.debug && log.warnEnabled) {
    log.warn "Invocation of <r:resource> for a resource that apparently doesn't exist: ${info.uri}"
}
...
```

Comment: Could you explain where you made this change?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to happen only when you try to use a sub directory when using the `dir` param. You would need to specify a `uri`. I'm assuming that `dir` can only be a single level directory.

You could try the following (from [plugin docs](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/4.%20Using%20resources.html)) :

```
<r:img uri="images/logo.png" width="100" height="50"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

uou are using 'grails-resources' plugin. It has also tag 'resource'. try to use direct G-tag:

```
<img src="${g.resource(dir: 'images/brochure', file: 'arrow_up.png', absolute: 'true')}" alt="Up" />
```

or use R-tag from resources plugin (RECOMMENDED):

```
<img src="${r.resource(uri: 'images/brochure/arrow_up.png')}" />
```

Get more info [here](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/guide/4.%20Using%20resources.html#4.2%20Linking%20to%20images)

Comment: Those both simply delegate to the resources plugin

Comment: no. i used namespace to direct definition. If resource-plugin is installed 'resource' tag is associated with 'r' namespace by default.